# Decimal that starts with 0 causes a 404 when looking for it's controller

Tags: .net, web-services, controllers, asp.net-mvc-controller

Sorry guys I know there must be a simple solution for this but I cannot find it. We are passing a variable called 'amount' (decimal) to a controller. If the amount is 1.00 or over the controller works fine. If the amount 0.99 or lower the same function cannot find the controller:

From Main Client Application:

```
private async Task<bool> GenerateUIDTransaction(decimal amount)
    {
        uidTransaction = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response =
                        await HttpClientHelper.getOneObjectAsync("api/Transaction/GetLastUIDTransaction/" + amount);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Object obj = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Object>();
                uidTransaction = obj.ToString();
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

From the Client Helper (which is part of the Main Client):

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> getOneObjectAsync(string path, List<KeyValuePair<String,String>> Headers =null)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        CreateHeaders(client);
        //If headers are present, we add it to the request Headers
        if(Headers != null)
        {
            foreach(KeyValuePair<String,String> pair in Headers)
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
            }
        }
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);

        client.Dispose();
        return response;
    }
```

The Actual Controller that the helper is supposed to find:

```
public class TransactionController : ApiController
{
    [Route("GetLastUIDTransaction/{amount}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage getLastUIDTransaction(decimal amount)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        string uidTransaction = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            uidTransaction = FacadeTransaction.GenerateUIDTransaction(amount).Result;
            return response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, uidTransaction);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Once again, if the first digit before the '.' is 0 it will NOT find the controller (404), all decimal values ABOVE 0.99 work fine. I know the function for the controller works but I included it just in case. Does anyone know of a solution that does NOT involve parsing the decimal into a string? As I would like to keep passing decimal amounts if possible.

Comment: But when you concatenate your amount to the path string you are already using an automatic conversion to a string. This will make your path variable according to the conversion rules of your locale

Comment: So my auto conversion could be ignoring the first 0? Thanks I will check this.

Comment: The path string 'path', reads as follows with decimal amount of 0.01: api/Transaction/GetLastUIDTransaction/0.01 which seems correct to me. And actually wow, it appears the problem lies only if there are numbers other than zero after the decimal place, the actual decimal point is what's failing. Our client uses rounded prices. "16.00" for example, which passes a "16" into the link. So the problem is with the point.